# Apple Secure Transport API is deprecated, what alternatives are there

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, swift-nio, secure-transport

Hi according to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secure_transport) the API is deprecated and considered legacy. It is not specific about when it will be removed. They recommend using Network, though it doesn't have a low-level API for alternative transports/physical layers.

I plan on using it for securing Bluetooth communications (like a BLE Uart thing), which means the API should not be dependent on network transports. Secure Transport fits this bill.

1. Is it okay to use this for future-safe developments?
2. Is there an alternative that will support something with an obscure transport layer (like BLE)?

I've looked at [Swift-nio](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio) and its children, and it looks like it may work when overriding Channel etc, though it is more geared toward network transports.

Comment: Using a deprecated security framework is always a risk; will it get patches or as much attention as a non-deprecated framework?  Will it get new encryption capabilities?  You may be better off looking at OpenSSL.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm okay if it doesn't get updated till the end of time. But I'm more concerned that they drop the API completely and it cannot be used in a generation or two at all